# A set of $d$ points in projective space may be described with polynomials of degree $d-1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Exercise 1.3 in Harris' Algebraic Geometry.

> Show that if $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ consists of $d$ points and is not contained in a line, then $\Gamma$ may be described as the zero locus of polynomials of degree $d-1$ and less

This can be strengthened to not include the "and less" addendum as he remarks later.

My first instinct was to induct on $d$ to show that for any $p \not\in \Gamma$ we can find a polynomial which is zero on $\Gamma$ but does not vanish on $p$. However I'm struggling with the base case: given two "points", how can one come up with a polynomial of degree $1$ that vanishes on both points but not elsewhere? This definitely goes against my current intuition of polynomials $p$ over $\mathbb{C}$ which have at most $deg(p)$ distinct roots, but I suppose that intuition doesn't hold here.

Comment: Can two points ever be not on a line?

Comment: @Mohan Yeah, this textbook has been pretty confusing so far. I think the point is that these points are points in projective space, hence are "lines" themselves.